# How can I write a PowerShell program that will Average CPU consumption over the time range of 15 minutes

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage

How can I write a PowerShell program that will Average CPU consumption over the time range of 15 minutes?

Below is my sample command

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average | Out-File c:\RM.txt -Encoding utf8
```

PowerShell program that will Average CPU consumption over the time range of 15 minutes

Comment: Why not use performance counters instead?

Comment: I need to write a code that will generate ticket if the CPU utilization will up by 95% for 15 mins of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this gives you 60 values of per-10 seconds CPU time average:

```
GET-COUNTER -Counter "\Prozessor(_Total)\Prozessorzeit (%)" -SampleInterval 10 -MaxSamples 60 |select -ExpandProperty countersamples | select -ExpandProperty cookedvalue
```

then you can proceed with `measure-object` to gather the average.

the performance counter will be named according to your OS language settings: english:  `"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"`

be aware that ticket generation depending on CPU usage is usually always provided by system management agents on servers especially in cloud environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure CPU usage over a period of time, you should use `Get-Counter`.

The example below measures the CPU usage of a system for 15 minutes (900 seconds) and gets the average from all the samples:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 MaxSamples 900  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue | Measure-Object -Average
```

Usually, getting a sample every 5 seconds is sufficient so you could also do this:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 5 MaxSamples 180  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CookedValue | Measure-Object -Average
```

This will get the cpu usage every 5 seconds and gets 180 samples in total, resulting in 900 seconds/15 minutes.